# how to select form ngrx store within an Effect using a slector with parameters

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I need to build an Effect and I need a value from the store, the problem is that the selector is a selector with parameters.

following the example code:

```
        @Effect()
      ExampleEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(
          ActionTypes.SOMETHING
        ),
        map((action: Somthing) => action.payload.myParameter),
// HERE I NEED THE PARAMETER TO PERFROM THE SELECTION
        withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(selectorWithParamter(myParameter))),
        map((value) => /* do somthing with the array [myParameter, valueSelected from sotre]*/)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write an arrow function to pass parameters while creating a selector.

```
export const getAlbumById = (collectionId: number) => createSelector(getAlbumEntities, entities => entities[collectionId]);
```

More example

// effect

```
@Effect({ dispatch: true })
  upsertAlbum$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AlbumActionTypes.UpsertAlbum),
    map((action: any) => action.payload),
    mergeMap(({ album }) =>
      this.store.pipe(
        select(selectAlbumIfExists(album.id)),
        first(),
        map(isAlbumHasName => [album, isAlbumHasName])
      )
    ),
    filter(([album, isAlbumHasName]) => !isAlbumHasName),
    map(([album]) => new LoadAlbum({ album }))
  );
```

// selector

```
export const selectAlbumIfExists = (id: string) =>
  createSelector(
    selectAlbumsEntities,
    entities => !!(entities[id] && entities[id].name)
  );
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create specific selectors and use them when calling `withLatestFrom`.

```
 approve$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(myactions.approve),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectReference), this.store.select(selectWork)),
      switchMap(([_, reference, work]) => this.service.approve(reference, work)),
      map(() => actions.approveSuccess())
    );
  });
```

As suggested above, try to use selectors. In my case,

> selectReference

and

> selectWork

are  NGRX selectors and the code looks like this:

```
//create slice
const requestState= createFeatureSelector<IRequestState>(feature);

//get exactly what you need from the state, not extra stuff
export const selectReference= createSelector(requestState, (state) => state?.reference);

export const selectWork= createSelector(requestState, (state) => state.Work);
```

Keep it clean, don't repeat the selection code. I doubt you need the selector with params. Try getting the list in a selector and the parameter via another selector. do the logic in the switchMap function (or whatever fits you the best, mergeMap or concatMap)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `props` object?

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props

Answer (score 1):

`andreisrob`'s suggestion is a good one. A fully working example is provided below. This shows how an effect can use a value from a selector that requires parameters.

```
updateQuestionnaireTranslationValue$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(QuestionnaireTranslationsUpdateValueAction),
    concatMap((action) => {
        this.store.dispatch(GlobalLoadingStartedAction({ message: "Updating translation value ..."}));

        const props = { formId: action.payload.formId, langId: action.payload.translationLanguageId};
        const update$ = this.store.pipe(
            select(selectQuestionnaireTranslationResourceCount, props),
            first(),
            concatMap(translatableCount => {
                const updateRes$ = this.questionnaireService.updateTranslation(action.payload, translatableCount).pipe(
                    tap(() => this.store.dispatch(GlobalLoadingEndedAction())),
                    catchError(err => {
                        this.store.dispatch(GlobalLoadingEndedAction());
                        this.logger.logErrorMessage("Error updating translation value: " + err);
                        this.snackBar.openError("Failed to update translation value");

                        this.store.dispatch(QuestionnaireTranslationsUpdateValueCancelledAction());
                        return of(null);
                    })
                );
                return updateRes$;
            })
        );
        return update$.pipe(map(count => ({ value: action.payload, totalCount: count } )));
    }),
    map((payload: ({ value: QuestionnaireTemplateTranslationUpdateValue, totalCount: number })) => {
        return QuestionnaireTranslationsUpdateValueDoneAction({ payload });
    }))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

NgRx introduced an operator called `concatLatestFrom` which lets you use the action's payload when selecting store data:

```
exampleEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(SomeAction),
    concatLatestFrom(action => this.store.select(selectorWithParameter(action.someParameter))),
    map(([action, valueOfSelectorWithParameter]) => /* do something */)
});
```

Comment: `concatLatestFrom` is not introduced by NGRX, but it's RXJS operator.

Comment: @MaihanNijat `concatLatestFrom` comes from the @ngrx/operators package. It's defined here- https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/main/modules/operators/src/concat_latest_from.ts#L46-L65. I actually implemented it!