# Howto retrieve a value from ngrx store in effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, selector, effect

I am newbie in nrgx in angular.

I am trying to retrieve a value from my store in Effect.ts
I create my custom Router, save it in the store, and I also create my selector called getRouterState.

How should I do it on this effect?

```
  login$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AuthActions.login),
    switchMap( () => combineLatest([this.authService.initializeLogin()])),
    switchMap( ([profile]) => {
                              if (profile)
                                {
                                  return of(loginSuccess({ userProfile:profile, isLoggedIn:true }));
                                }
                                  return of(logoutSuccess());
                              }),

    tap((interaction) => {
      if(interaction.type === AuthActionEnum.LogoutSuccess) {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/unauthenticated');
      }
  if(interaction.type === AuthActionEnum.LoginSuccess) {
         //Here I need to read the store, this give  always route.url = undefined 
         this.store.select(getRouterState).subscribe(route => 
     {
           //console.log(route.url); 
           this.router.navigateByUrl(route.url); 
         });

      }
    })));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to select form ngrx store within an Effect using a slector with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53519731/how-to-select-form-ngrx-store-within-an-effect-using-a-slector-with-parameters)

Comment: Thanks The Fabio, I will check your sugestion  and I will give you my feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to split that effect out into multiple smaller effects.

- One effect to dispatch the success/logout action
- Second effect that listens to logout and navigates to `/unauthenticated`
- Third effect that listens to succes, then reads store with `concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(getRouterState))`, and then navigates to the url retrieved from the store

Comment: Hi timdeschryver, thanks,  you are right, I also think this the best way. The Fabio, I tried your sugestion but I was not well suceed. Thanks to both for the help.